# iOS Switching Views 1 view back

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I started the iOS development yesterday and tried to set up 2 switching views. That wasn't really a problem with the help of a tutorial. Then I thought: Let's make a third view. All went fine but then when I tried to switch back from the 3rd to the 2nd it switches to the 1.
When I tried to use [self presentModalViewController...] it switches forward to the views i wrote there but not backwards. And with [self dismiss...] it just switches to the 1st view all the time. Is there a possibility to make this switch where ever I want? 3 to 2, 2 to 1, 3 to 1 etc.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

When you say switching views you are referring to view controllers. There can be many ways to switch between controllers.

First and foremost one is Push to a new view controller. This can be achieved only when the current view controller holds a navigation controller on it. A navigation controller is the one which lets you navigate between view controllers. And when you are navigated to a new controller using 'pushViewController' method, then you need to come back to previous controller using 'popviewcontroller method of the navigation controller'. This allows you to pop back to previous screen/controller.

However, whenever you push to a new controller this means, you are adding/inserting one controller into the stack, and as you know stack is LIFO, last one will have to be out of the stack first then only you can get other elements of the stack.

So, for example: if you have 3 controllers A, B and C. You started off from A and pushed to B, and then further pushed to C from B. then the stack will have CBA (C will be on top and A will be on bottom). So you will have to pop out C first and then B etc.

Other ways of moving to a new controller is : presentModalViewController to present a screen/controller and this can be removed using dismissmodalviewcontroller method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good explanation of what this user needs to look at - UINavigationController implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For move forward you can use UINavigation controller like below:

```
FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstViewController animated:YES];
  [firstViewController release];
```

myViewController is object of your viewcontroller. & for one view back use only below line:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you work with one viewContoller and switch between different views like:

```
[view1 removeFromSuperview];
[myRootView addSubview: view2];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you present a modal view controller, you need to dismiss it before proceeding. In particular you can't modally present view controller 1, then modally present view controller 2, then modally present view controller 1.

At the very least you must dismiss modal view controller 2 – then 1 should still be there.

Depending on the nature of these controllers, UINavigationController or view swapping may be a better route to take.